# Firing a trigger group multiple times on a page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need some help with Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics.

I want to send a pageview to Google Analytics if a user is viewing an image in a gallery on an article. The user is staying on the same URL, when he is viewing an image.

I created a trigger group which consists of two events

• Consent given by the user to use Google Analytics
• Event which is fired when an image in a gallery is being viewed

This works so far so good. Unfortunately, the trigger group is only being fired once on a page. When a user open the gallery and views the image and scrolls to next image, he is staying on the same URL. In that case, the trigger group is only being fired once.

How can I achieve that the trigger group is being fired multiple times on the same page without removing the second trigger (consent)?

I found out that I can create a second trigger group and add two image views and the consent as a trigger. But this solution means that I have to create 100 new tags, which is kind of crazy. Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once consent has been given by the user in a way that each pageview can pick up (e.g. you're setting it in some persisted state: data layer, cookie, etc.), you're ultimately just looking at triggering when the event happens.

Since you describe a scenario where it happens only once, I'd urge you to take a look at the other triggers on your tag and remove the page-specific trigger your description suggests you have in place. Replace it with only your event and consent triggers and it should work every time an event is observed.